# redis-server hangs up after call. won't start

Tags: ubuntu, redis, installation

Im trying to start the redis after my setup, but when I try to service redis-server start it doesn't do anything but hangs up. when I try to view the log using systemctl status redis-server.service
it print me this warnings and err
[image]

[image]

I tried to stop the redis server but it hang up does not print anything at all.
I am very new to redis I had no clue what is going on. please help me thank you in advance.

Comment: The warnings that you are referring to in the log are simply warnings about settings that could be dangerous in certain situations.  Can you be more specific on what you mean by hangs-up?  Are you unable to connect to the server process using the redis-cli?

Comment: Hi! thanks, I figured it out. seems like server is already running and I had to stop other process to be able to start new one by going to `lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` and kill the process. everything went wel except when I start the server `service redis-server start` it give me this msg : `Job for redis-server.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` how am I able to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's running on the foreground.

You can send it to background by hitting `Ctrl-Z` on the same terminal, or you can open a new terminal and connect to the running server instance with `redis-cli`.

`redis-cli` is the terminal client you use to issue commands to redis server.

If you hit `Ctrl-Z` on the terminal as I explained, then if you want to stop the running instance on the first terminal (i.e. kill redis server), issue `fg` to bring the process to foreground once more, and hit `Ctrl-C`.